# Orocommerce - generate API client libraries

Tags: swagger, openapi, orocommerce

I am quite new in the orocommerce ecosystem, and I would like to generate API client librairies automatically for orocommerce API (frontend and backend). The objective is to build my own UI.

I found some dependencies on NelmioApiDocBundle than could potentially generate swagger file, but I hit multiple problems:

- this is a quite old version, that only support swagger 1.2
- the generated file (using `symfony run php bin/console api:swagger:dump  /tmp/api/`) seems not working with swagger codegen "as is"
- all the part of the API seems not written using NelmioApiDocBundle annotation

I am wondering if there is an other mechanism to generate API client librairies for orocommerce. I would like a SDK for typescript.

Thanks in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the only supported swagger version is 1.2, as you stated.

By default, the `api:swagger:dump` command works with an outdated API, to generate data for the current API, run it with `--view=rest_json_api` option:

```sh
api:swagger:dump --view=rest_json_api
```

As an alternative to the API client generation, as Oro API strictly follows JSON.API standard, you can use many existing client libraries, compatible with the JSON.API specification. The list of Typescript implementations can be found at the official website: https://jsonapi.org/implementations/#client-libraries-typescript

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will look at it and share my results when I found a good solution. For me the problem with JSONAPI is it does not generates the DTO objects.

Comment: I try to generate the API and data model objects with swagger codegen CLI but with no success. Do you know if this is still supported (ie spec file compliant) ?
The command I used: `docker run --rm -v /tmp/:/tmp swaggerapi/swagger-codegen-cli:2.4.19 generate -i /tmp/api3/api-docs.json -l typescript-angular  -o /tmp/dist/`

Comment: "Swagger Codegen 2.X supports Swagger/OpenAPI version 2." Oro generates Swagger version 1.2 spec.

Comment: Normally, version 2 supports spec starting from 1.0 according to this table: https://swagger.io/docs/open-source-tools/swagger-codegen/

Comment: I managed to convert the swagger spec 1.2 to a 2.x with an external lib. Now generation is working. During this time I discover that "responseModel in the original swagger spec file is empty, like the model object name "models":{"" .... Do you know if it is a bug on your side or an expected behavior ? For example, models shoud have been "models":{"Product" ... for admin-api-products.json

Comment: As this generator is a third party package feature that is not widely used in customizations, and it's not tested in core, I don't have an answer.